# Unable to understand string escaping from onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, onclick

I have a method defined as below :

```
function updateManagerPreferences(companyId, managerId, userId) {
  console.log('inside method');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: admin_url + "/updatemanager/" + companyId + "/" 
    + managerId + "/" + userId,
    encode: false,
    crossDomain: true
  }).done(function (tresult) {
    var success_result = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(tresult));
    console.log(success_result);
  });
}
```

It takes 3 parameters from a button onclick and I am trying to call the method as follows :

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success' value='Update' onclick='updateManagerPreferences(" + companyId + "," + $('#managerDropDown').val() + "," + result.ResponseMessage.users[i].user_id + ");'/>
```

I refered all the similar stackoverflow answers but none of them have helped.

Can someone please tell where am I going wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a + before managerId in the url of your $.ajax call.

Comment: Is the HTML being generated from JS or some other language? The string delimiters don't make much sense. You can also avoid the entire string concatenation mess if you use unobtrusive event handlers.

Comment: how about using hidden field to store that value ??

Comment: @CF256 Sorry it was mistakenly edited while writing the question here. It exists in the code. editted the question

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by getting directly your value from inside function and element value by jQuery .

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success' value='Update' id='updatemanager' />

<script>
$("#updatemanager").on("click",function(){
  var managerId = $('#managerDropDown').val();
  var userId = result.ResponseMessage.users[i].user_id;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: admin_url + "/updatemanager/" + companyId + "/" 
    + managerId + "/" + userId,
    encode: false,
    crossDomain: true
  }).done(function (tresult) {
    var success_result = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(tresult));
    console.log(success_result);
  });
});
</script>
```